# quartz cron that will run on 15 and the last day of month

Tags: cron, quartz-scheduler

Hi I tries to set a quartz job that will run on the 15 and the last day of month.

This is not working:

```
0 0 0 15,L * ? *
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the CronTrigger tutorial (http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-06.html):

> When using the ‘L’ option, it is important not to specify lists, or ranges of values, as you’ll get confusing/unexpected results.

What you can do is to use 2 separate triggers that execute the same command:

```
0 0 0 15 * ? *
```

and

```
0 0 0 L * ? *
```

Hope this helps your problem.